# Same CIDR block in the same region

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc

I realised that I can create multiple VPC using the same CIDR block belonging to the same region. Even the subnet can be the same.

What is the use case for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, as a VPC is a total network, it makes it possible to create multiple networks in the same region that have the same IP range.

Its important to note that you can't just send traffic between VPCs in the same region using private IPs as VPCs are completely isolated from each other. To achieve this behavior, you would need to create a VPC peering connection and if two VPCs have overlapping IP ranges, they cannot be peered.

There is no particular use case for it though. Some people might use it for different environments eg. Testing and production and they might want to keep a standard IP range between the two.

This is simply something that comes along with the fact that VPCs are separate and isolated entities.